# How to put a button on the same line as some text?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and trying to place a button on the same line as some text without luck. I've made a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/fm042g2u/5/). What am I missing? Many thanks.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 center-block">
 <br>
<p>Put the button on the same line as this text.</p>

<span class="pull-right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small" name="submit" id="submit">+ Add Me</button></span>
<br>
 </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've made a slight change to your code to put the button on the same line. Here's how it looks like now-

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 center-block">
     <br>
     <p>Put the button on the same line as this text. <span class="pull-right">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small" name="submit" id="submit">+ Add Me</button></span></p>
     <br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a div containing your button and then `pull-right` it:

```
<div class="container">
  <span>Put the button on the same line as this text.</span>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <div class="btn btn-small">+ Add Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Try it on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/v0sc608x/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 center-block">
 <br>
<p>Put the button on the same line as this text.</p>

<span class="pull-right">
<button style =" margin-top:0px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small" name="submit" id="submit">+ Add Me</button></span>
<br>
 </div>
  </div>
```